# Jquery URL Change on click

Tags: jquery

How can I change url of a picture on clicking a button.

**the puspose is differentiate the url. 1y1.png = (group1)y(group2).png Each time when click on one of three buttons of group1, it gives me a predetermined letter at the url instead of (group1).**

For intance; I have those pictures under images folder.

1y1.png
1y2.png
1y3.png
2y1.png
2y2.png
2y3.png
3y1.png
3y2.png
3y3.png

And I have 6 buttons into two groups. The first groups chages the first numbers at the url. And the second group is changing the third letter at the url.

First groups determines the background color and second group determines the image inside. For intance 1y1.png is a picture with white background and there is a girl inside. Second ones (1y2.png) has boys instead of the girl. Third one (1y3.png) also with a white background and it has baby inside. And if we chose second option from first group we can we are going to have url changed to 2y1.png this picture has girl inside but with blue bacground.

How could that be possible with jquery. Is there a simple sample.

I think the coding should be something like that

```
function pictureselect(model)
{
    var gruop1 = $.cookie('background');
    if(gruop1==undefined){
        colori = 1;
        }
    var detayselect = $.cookie('detay');
     if((detayselect!=undefined)&&(detayselect!=0)){
     $("#yaka").attr("src", "resim/"+gruop1+"y"+gruop2+".png");
         }else{
     $("#yaka").attr("src", "resim/"+gruop1+"y"+gruop1+".png");      
             }
     $("#yaka").css({"display":""});
     $.cookie('images',model);
}
```

Comment: You should post the code

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you want to do from your description.

Answer (score 1):

So, you mean something like this :

```
$('.image_group_1').click(function(){
    $("#image_id_1").attr("src", $(this).attr('src'));      
});
$('.image_group_2').click(function(){
    $("#image_id_2").attr("src", $(this).attr('src'));      
});
$('.image_group_3').click(function(){
    $("#image_id_3").attr("src", $(this).attr('src'));      
});

<img src='1y1.png' class='image_group_1' />
<img src='1y2.png' class='image_group_1' />
<img src='1y3.png' class='image_group_1' />
<img src='2y1.png' class='image_group_2' />
<img src='2y2.png' class='image_group_2' />
<img src='3y3.png' class='image_group_2' />
<img src='3y1.png' class='image_group_3' />
<img src='3y2.png' class='image_group_3' />
<img src='3y3.png' class='image_group_3' />


<img src='' id='image_id_1' /> 
<img src='' id='image_id_2' />
<img src='' id='image_id_3' />
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot , but I guess this coding changes pictures on click  next function. I don't want that. People can directly choose one of them.

Comment: Isn't there something possible at this coding. As you see there is two veriables. group1 and group2 into url. $("#yaka").attr("src", "resim/"+gruop1+"y"+gruop2+".png");
By giving the buttons a function like if you clicked make gruop1 to "1" for group1's first button.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your image source as follows :

```
var = "your url";
$("#imgId").attr("src", src);
```

Comment: I mean I don't want to change whole url. Just want to change it part by part. For 1+y+1.png On clicking first group's second button url will be 2+y+1.png. Also if I click second group's third button url will be 2+y+3.png.